# Why is R multicore only using one core?

Tags: r, multicore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parallel processing in R limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924698/parallel-processing-in-r-limited)

I've written some code in R multicore, and I'm running it on a 24-core machine.  In fact there are only 12 cores, but they are hyperthreaded, so it looks like there are 24.

Here's what's strange: all the threads run on the same single core!  So they each only use a tiny amount of cpu, instead of each running on a single core, and chewing up all available cores.

For simplicity, I'm just running 4 threads:

```
mclapply( 1:30, function(size) {
    # time consuming stuff that is cpu bound (think "forecast.ets" et al)
}, mc.cores = 4, mc.preschedule = F )
```

Prior to running this, there is already an R process running on one core, using 100% of that core's capacity:

[image]

Next, I launch the "multicore process", and 4 extra threads fight for the same core!:

[image]

... so, they each get 12%  of one core, or about 1% of the available processing power, when they should each be able to get 100% of one core.  Also, the other R process now only get 50% of the core.

OS is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.  Hardware is Intel.  R is version 2.15.2 "trick or treat"

Thoughts?  (I know I could just use snowfall, but I have a ton of variables, and I really don't want to have to `sfExport` all of them!)

Edit: oh, I guess there's some global lock somewhere?  But still, why would there be a conflict between two completely separate R processes?  I can run two R processes in parallel just fine, with each taking 100% of a core's CPU.

Edit2: Thanks to Dirk's pointer, I rebuilt openblas, and it's looking much healthier now!:

[image]

Comment: Have you run "registerDC" before "doMC" ?

Comment: Haven't heard of either, so no, and I will go and find what those are now.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using the multicore package that comes with R, as the `parallel` package.  There doesn't seem to be either of those two functions.  Should I be better off downloading the raw `multicore` package instead of using `parallel`?

Comment: No. Did you read the vignette that came with the package?

Comment: No.  I will go and look for a vignette now.  I read the `multicore.pdf` file, and the `?multicore` output.

Comment: `vignette("parallel")` "Vignette 'multicore' not found"; `vignette("parallel")` "Vignette 'parallel' not found".  What command should I use to open the vignette?

Comment: That should've worked (and works for me). Alternatively, Googling "R parallel package" gives it to me as well: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible issue is a possible side effect of the OpenBLAS package which sets CPU affinity such that processes stick to one core.  See [Parallel processing in R limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924698/parallel-processing-in-r-limited) for a discussion and link to more discussion on the r-sig-hpc list which has a fix.

Comment: Is that not what I have in the third line of my code above? `}, mc.cores = 4, mc.preschedule = F )`

Comment: Yes but if you want 24, setting 4 won't help :)  I recommend a simple example -- such as the `while(1)` I had there and just call some simple base functions.

Comment: Do you have `libopenblas-base` installed?  There is an issue with CPU affinity.  See Claudia Beleites answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924698/parallel-processing-in-r-limited

Comment: Yes, I'm using openblas.  I will take a look at that page.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the solution.  Well found!  Do you want to put that in an answer, and I'll mark that as 'accepted'?

Comment: @HughPerkins: or maybe close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Joshua, it does seem suspiciously similar I confess.