# Activate R Multicore for openmp

Tags: r, parallel-processing, openmp, intel

I have compiled R 3.4.3 using `qopenmp` ([Intel qopenmp](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/682582)). I am struggling to get R to run my Rscript on anything more than 1 cpu core out of the 12 physical cpu cores available. That 1 CPU is running 100% of the code, while the other 11 remain totally idle.

I have tried to wrap my code using h2o, doMC and parallel R packages, however am not having any success.

I have studied at length existing SO posts (e.g. [Why is R multicore only using one core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126990/why-is-r-multicore-only-using-one-core)), however they all relate to rebuilding openBLAS which I believe to be unrelated to my problem.

Can anyone guide me on how to make the Rscript run all of the system cores noting the `qopenmp` compiled version of R3.4.3? Do I need to change a cpu affinity setting for `qopenmp` when compiling R / and how would I do this?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: You assume R would magically become multi-threaded -- but it does not and cannot (due to internals of the language design and implementation; with the exception of some fairly localized internal operations).  So to a first approximation, all you have is what it in the (excellent) vignette of the `parallel` package that came with R:  explicit process-parallel approaches.

Comment: Hi Dirk - big follower of your posts and your guidance is invaluable. Sounds like I was somewhat (albeit amateurish) on the right path with parallel...I shall re-review the vignette.

Comment: Show the code that you want to do in parallel.